# TensorFlow efficient shared memory allocation for recursive concatenation

Tags: python, c++, memory-management, tensorflow

DenseNets tend to take up a lot of memory in TensorFlow because each concat operation is stored in a separate allocation. A recent paper, [Memory-Efficient Implementation of DenseNets](http://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06990), demonstrates that this memory utilization can be dramatically reduced through sharing of allocations. This image from the paper + pytorch implementation illustrates the shared memory approach:

[image: densenet shared memory]

How can this be implemented with TensorFlow? If it can't be done via python, how can it be properly implemented in an Op with CPU and GPU support?

- [Pytorch efficient DenseNet implementation](https://github.com/gpleiss/efficient_densenet_pytorch)
- [Keras DenseNet Implementation](https://github.com/titu1994/keras-contrib/blob/ff47da56fbd54cf6cdc2ac2218529fbdadf99296/keras_contrib/applications/densenet.py) with "naive" allocations, works with TensorFlow backend.

I've created a [TensorFlow Feature Request for necessary allocation functionality](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12948).

Comment: This is a powerful idea and if it can't be done in Python, I wouldn't know why, because absolutely everything else in Python is susceptible to this kind of technique.

Comment: However if the needed parts of Tensorflow are written in another language, the shared memory is treated differently or specially arranged, or otherwise something comes up, you're going to end up having to do major surgery and probably have a lot of cascading issues and errors when you to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

A memory efficient implementation is now available at:

https://github.com/joeyearsley/efficient_densenet_tensorflow

The relevant function from the above link is:

```
# Gradient checkpoint the layer
_x = tf.contrib.layers.recompute_grad(_x)
```